# How to write a Terminal command to unrar a file in specific location?

Tags: mac, terminal, homebrew

On my Mac, I want to decompress a `.rar` in Downloads. I have hombrew and an unrar script already installed from GitHub; unfortunately, when I prompt the Terminal to `unrar` the file, I constantly get:

```bash
~ % unrar/Users/JP1/Downloads/remixpack.rar  

  zsh: no such file or directory: unrar/Users/J1/Downloads/remixpack.rar
```

Is there an error in the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew install unar`

It's the CLI version of https://theunarchiver.com/command-line

to use, simply

`unar my_archive.rar`

Answer (score 2):

Add a SPACE between `unrar` (the command) and it's argument (the filename).

On a general level - [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) has at least two "Bash guides", skimming through them will enlighten on the use of the terminal.

Then, `zsh` has features not found in Bash.

Due to the amount of available information; As a beginner, I'd recommend switch to Bash so that all examples and documents are applicable.

Comment: Thanks. So It should be like this? JP ~ % unrar remixpack.rar /Users/JP1/Downloads/remixpack.rar

Comment: One *.rar file at a time. `unrar ` on it's own will print a long text, tersely telling details on how to use it. In that text, note that there is only one `<archive>`

Comment: Note: `unrar -x archive.rar /where/to/put/files/ ` - leave out all of `/where/...` to place them in `./` (current dir)